# gitweb on Ubuntu Server as Location/Directory instead of Virtual Host

Tags: ubuntu, git

Since DynDNS no longer resolves subdomains for free I have to use gitweb on a subdir of the apache2. Usual suspects such as Pro Git suggest something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gitserver
    DocumentRoot /srv/gitosis/repositories/
    <Directory /srv/gitosis/repositories/>
        Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi
        DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried various variations using Location and Directory tags with different attribute combinations without any notable success.

My first Idea was close to the following

```
Alias /gitweb /srv/gitosis/repositories
<Location /gitweb>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "gitweb Repository view"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/gitweb.passwd
    Require valid-user
    SSLRequireSSL
    SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /etc/gitweb.conf
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
</Location>
```

Apache is in the gitosis group, the repositories are readable and executable for that group.

So, what is the indended way to get websvn run on Ubuntu 10?

EDIT: using "git instaweb --httpd=apache2" in a repo as user gitosis works fine

Comment: What exactly is the problem you encounter? Error message when requesting gitweb? Something in the apache2 error logs?

Comment: Using the upper configuration I connect to https://server/gitweb/ but after logging in I only get the standard directory tree view. That may be ok for the repositories dir, but when diving into the repos the view should change.

Comment: Not really a solution, but [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) will definitely not work since it’s a relative URL, not a file system path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got some solution, or at least a workaround as it doesn't seem to be very elegant.
I use the existing ssl vhost with the following config:

```
Alias /gitweb /usr/lib/cgi-bin
Alias /gitweb.css /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.css
Alias /git-favicon.png /usr/share/gitweb/git-favicon.png
Alias /git-logo.png /usr/share/gitweb/git-logo.png
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Gitweb Repository View"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/gitweb.passwd
    Require valid-user
    SSLRequireSSL
    Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I don't like those aliases, but at least it works without touching the cgi.